How does Meta Llama-3 LLM compare against GPT 4, Claude Opus, and Mistral-Large on human evaluations?
https://ai.meta.com/blog/meta-llama-3 compared Meta Llama-3 LLM against GPT 3.5, Claude Sonnet and Mistral Medium on human evaluations:

They conveniently avoided the state-of-the-art LLMs, namely GPT 4, Claude Opus and Mistral-Large.
How does Meta Llama-3 LLM compare against GPT 4, Claude Opus, and Mistral-Large on human evaluations?

https://chat.lmsys.org/ now has human evaluations for Llama-3 LLM, which allows us to compare against GPT 4, Claude Opus, and Mistral-Large:



What's really interesting is that, when restricted to English-language prompts, Llama3-70b-instruct is within the margin of error of being ranked first.
